# Differential of boundary morphisms in the moduli space of pointed stable curves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Recall that first order deformations of a smooth pointed curve $(C,p_1,\ldots,p_n)$ are parametrized by $H^1(C,\cal{T}_C(-p_1-\ldots-p_n))$ and in the stable case is $Ext^1(\Omega_C^1,\cal{O}_C(-p_1-\ldots-p_n))$. On the other hand there are two well known classes of boundary maps
$$\eta_i:\cal{M}_{i,k+1}\times\cal{M}_{g-i,n-k+1}\to\overline{\cal{M}}_{g,n}$$
and
$$\eta_0:\cal{M}_{g-1,n+2}\to\overline{\cal{M}}_{g,n}.$$
the first one identify the last marked point of a genus $g-i$ curve with the last one of a genus $i$ curve. This map dominates the boundary divisor $\Delta_{i,k}\subset\overline{\cal{M}}_{g,n}$. The Second map identify the last two marked points of a genus $g-1$ curve and again it dominates $\Delta_0$. Can anyone give me some information about 
$$d\eta_i:H^1(C_1,{\cal{T}}_{C_1}(-p_{i_1}-\ldots-p_{i_k}-q))\times H^1(C_2,{\cal{T}}_{C_2}(-p_{j_1}-\ldots-p_{j_{n-k}}-q'))\to Ext^1(\Omega^1_C,\cal{O}_C(-p_1-\ldots-p_n))$$
where $C=C_1\cup C_2\big/q\sim q'$. Same for $\eta_0$. Rank, if it is degenerate, the kernel. There is some explicit Kodaira-Spencer type of theory for this maps?